# How to get this Heading style in css

Tags: html, css

Hi I was wondering to get this structure design in css, I want background and text over the background color but the background should be bit away from the opening text. I have attached the design layout
thanks
[image: this is the design layout]

Comment: You could try using `position:absolute`, but I'm not sure how to achieve that slanting border-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1:before {
  display: block;
  background-color: aqua;
  content: "";
  height: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: .5em;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Your Title Goes Here
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="title">
  Your title goes here
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

#title:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 36px;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: cyan;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
}
```